# How to automatically change colors in a row if one cell in the row is not blank?

Tags: excel

For example, if J2 is not blank anymore, the whole row turns green.

I have this written down:`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK($J$2)),TRUE,FALSE)`, and apply only to row 2. But I want to expand to the whole sheet, not just only row 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove dollar sign from in front of `2` like-

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK($J1)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

In fact you can simply use below formula.

```
=$J1<>""
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That helps a lot! I hope I can publically give you an upvote lol

Comment: Glad to know! Then please consider accepting the answer so that other user can know it solved.

Comment: Hi, sorry I just saw your reply. I'm still new to this platform. I've done that! Thanks again!